# How to store recursive ref inside of a struct

Tags: rust

Let's assume the following struct

```
struct Item<'a> {
    items: Vec<&'a Item<'a>>
}
```

Let's assume the following variable contains many `Item` objects with empty `items` field.

```
let mut items: Vec<Item<'a>> = get_items();
```

Let's assume I have the task to add to `items` field of each `Item` the references to all another `Item` objects in the `items` vector.

My current implementation is

```
struct Item<'a> {
    items: Vec<&'a Item<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Item<'a> {
    fn new() -> Item<'a> {
        Item { items: vec![] }
    }   
}

fn main() {
    let mut items = vec![Item::new(), Item::new()];
    while let Some(item) = items.pop() {
        for another_item in &mut items {
            item.items.push(another_item); 
        }   
        items.push(item);
    }   
}`
```

It fails because I do `item.items.push(another_item);`

Comment: Mistake. I make a mistake

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is unsound.  Without knowing your use-case, there isn't a good solution to your problem.

You have a couple of errors that relate to mutability.  With those fixed, your code becomes:

```
struct Item<'a> {
    items: Vec<&'a Item<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Item<'a> {
    fn new() -> Item<'a> {
        Item { items: vec![] }
    }   
}

fn main() {
    let mut items = vec![Item::new(), Item::new()];
    while let Some(mut item) = items.pop() {
        for another_item in items {
            item.items.push(&another_item); 
        }   
        items.push(item);
    }   
}
```

The compiler now complains about the lifetime of `another_item`:

> error: `another_item` does not live long enough

The `for` loop owns the `another_item`, and it cannot give ownership away back to the `Vec` of references.

Whatever you do, you can't get around this fundamental issue.  One reason behind these rules is that references are really just pointers.  As you move elements into and out of `items`, each `item` will change its location, rendering previously-created pointers to it invalid.  (This isn't Python, with magical garbage-collected references.)  Of course, the rules of Rust prevent such a situation from ever occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I ended with this code

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;

struct Item {
    items: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Item>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let items = vec![Item { items: Vec::new() }, Item { items: Vec::new() }];
    let iter = items.into_iter();
    let items = iter.map(|item| Rc::new(RefCell::new(item)));
    let items = items.collect::<Vec<_>>();
    for item_index in 0..items.len() {
        let item = items[item_index].clone();
        let mut item = item.borrow_mut();
        for another_item_index in 0..items.len() {
            if another_item_index == item_index {
                continue;
            }
            let another_item = items[another_item_index].clone();
            (*item).items.push(another_item);
        }
    }
}
```